# AngularJS request.POST return QueryDict: {}

Tags: python, angularjs, django

I am making a POST request in AngularJS as follows:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('app').controller('RegisterController', function($scope, $http) {
         $scope.login = []
         $scope.registrar = function() {

         $http({
            method  : 'POST',
            url     : '/register/',
            headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, 
            data    : {'username' : $scope.login.username,
                       'password' : $scope.login.password,
                       'email' : $scope.login.email, 
                       'permission' : $scope.login.permission }
          })          
          .success(function(data) {
            $scope.gists = data;
          })
          .error(function(data, status) {
            console.error('Repos error', status, data);
          })
          .finally(function() {
            console.log("finally finished repos");
          });   

        };
})
```

And in Django I'm calling request.POST["username"] method to get the information.

But information is not returning, I took a print command in request.POST and request.GET to see and both return QueryDict: {}.

I need to do some different configuration for the REST works?

Comment: Are you sure you are expecting application/json and not form encoded data?

Comment: Suggestion  ... no need to create whole object for `data` when your scope object has exact same properties. Change to `data: $scope.login`. Saves manually creating a new object. Won't resolve problem you have ... but help in future

Answer (score 2):

It's accessible via `request.body` so you need to do `json.loads(request.body)` to retrieve the posted data.

Also consider using [DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) instead. It will handle retrieving json payload automatically.

Comment: If you get a TypeError (must be string not bytes) then use: json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))